# How to run all inherited function by there virtual function?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, abstract

Suppose I have class `parent` and the inherited classes are `child1`, `child2`, and `child3`. All inherit the function `TellName` of `parent`. I want to know if there is any way to call the **class parent**'s `TellName` function and automatically run all functions of `child1`, `child2`, and `child3`.

*visualization:*

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void TellName() { }
};

class child1 : public parent
{
public:
    void TellName() override { std::cout<<"Child1"<<"\n"; }
};

class child2 : public parent
{
public:
    void TellName() override { std::cout<<"Child2"<<"\n"; }
};

class child3 : public parent
{
public:
    void TellName() override { std::cout<<"Child3"<<"\n"; }
};
```

*Now I want to run the `TellName` function of `parent` and get output as:*

```
>> Child1
>> Child2
>> Child3
```

<s>I am assuming that it is possible by using the VTable of the function `TellName`</s>. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: With the classes that you have, this is not possible. You don't have a single type which contains all those functions. You have to make multiple objects of different types and call that function on them.

Comment: An object of type `parent` doesn't have any `child1` or `child2` parts to it, including methods. The `parent` type doesn't know anything about the derived types.

Comment: `I am assuming that it is possible by using the VTable of the function TellName.` No, because there is no "vtable of the function TellName". There is a vtable *per class* not *per function*. In the vtable (for the class), the entry for the function points to the override for the class. You do not have a single vtable with all versions of tell name.

Comment: Before you ask how, you should ask why. By the looks of it, this is not good design.

Comment: 'Borgleader' Thanks for the information. Is it possible by the class VTable tho?

Comment: Your assumption that "it is possible by using the VTable" is deeply incorrect.  The C++ standard does not require that there even be a vtable. A vtable is a common way that modern compilers support virtual function dispatch, but different compilers do it differently. To exploit the vtable like you wish, you would need to go outside bounds of standard C++, and write code specific to each compiler (and often for compiler *versions*).  Within bounds of standard C++, you could concoct some scheme to instantiate EVERY derived class and then, for every object, call its virtual function.

Comment: So, the best way to do it is to create a static array/vector of function pointers, right?

Comment: Use `@username` when replying to send a notification to th person.

Comment: @Hassan   No.  For that to work, you would also need to incorrectly assume that a pointer to a (virtual) non-static member function is the same as a pointer to a non-member functions.   Directly calling a virtual function without referring to an object produces a diagnosable error and any scheme that might coerce the compiler to permit such a thing results in undefined behaviour.   [I gave a hint at one possible approach to get the output you seek, but the fact you concluded you need an array/vector of function pointers says you're missing the point].

Comment: @peter it means I have to pass the object's pointer ( child1, child2, or child3 ) to the function TellName of parent and call the child's TellName function from there. So if the parent class has a static array/vector which will store all pointers of child classes ( child1, child2, child3) it can run those's TellName functions using for loop. And the pointer of child classes could be passed through its constructor. Right?

Comment: @Hassan - A little closer.   There are ways to set it up so you can automate construction in a controlled manner of the array/vector of pointers to objects.   There are trade-offs in (and alternatives to) having statically allocated objects (or a vector) that you need to manage as well.   Bear in mind that the object must exist when you call the virtual member function (so you'll be in trouble if your vector contains a dangling pointer to an object that no longer exists).

Comment: I think you are not completly understand what `virtual` does. There is no standard ways to do what you want. I would say you will be better off to use `static` functions and variables to accomplish your task.

Comment: @Peter I think the null pointer problem can be solved using the destructor of the child classes. I will erase the pointer from the vector of parent class in the destructor call of child class.

Comment: @Hassan   There you go.  Think about it a bit more, and you'll see you don't need to touch the destructor of the "child" class.  Destructors of base classes are always called in the process of destroying an instance of a derived class.   But stay away from vtables, unless you're implementing a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The only standard way to do what you are trying to do using virtual functions is to instantatiate objects of all types and call `TellName()` function on them. I.e. something like this:

```
int main()
{
    child1 c1;
    child2 c2;
    child3 c3;
    c1.TellName();
    c2.TellName();
    c3.TellName();
}
```

Or, since you made `TellName()` function `virtual`, you can put all these objects in one container and print names by calling `TellName()` from `parent`'s pointer. Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<parent>> vec;
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<child1>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<child2>());
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<child3>());
    for (auto& ptr : vec) {
        ptr->TellName();
    }
}
```

BUT, if you want to print these names without instantiation of child objects, then you don't need and shouldn't use `virtual` functions. Instead you can use `static` functions.